# Rails - changing default param_key for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activemodel

I've been using plain Ruby form objects in rails, but to keep my code organized, I've ended up having to add a ton of namespaces to them.  So I'll have a form like:

```
class User::Registration::NewForm
  extend Forwardable
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  ...
end
```

The annoyance with this is that the param_key for my forms becomes kind of daunting, e.g. `user_registration_new_form`

I'd like to override this somehow, and I think I need to mess with the `model_name` and/or `param_key` methods from `ActiveModel::Naming` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Naming/param_key/class).  But I can't get it to work.

Has anyone been able to successfully override the default param_key for a model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gah, I finally got it!  You just need to define a class `model_name` method, and return an `ActiveModel::Name` object.

So something like:

```
self.model_name
  ActiveModel::Name.new(User)
end
```

Comment: I had to do `::ActiveModel::Name.new(User)` otherwise `uninitialized constant Reform::Form::ActiveModel::Name`.

Comment: You can also do something like: `def model_name; Struct.new(:param_key, :name).new('form', 'form');  end`.